# Multiple Replace in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

I am making a program i.e. a script converter. I tried the Replace Command
`TextBox1.Text.Replace("Hi", "Hello").Replace("Hello", "HI")`
But this doesn't work. It doesn't replace the second time correctly.

Please Help...

Comment: why don't you make it in 2 lines?

Comment: Are you *sure* the first one replace works?

Comment: @shahbaz I have updated my answer with what it seems you want. Please be aware that the reason myself and user1244383 both guessed wrong is because your question was not clear enough about what you were actually doing, and what you actually wanted to happen. Please ensure your questions are clear in the future.

Comment: @shahbaz When you select a correct answer, be sure to up-vote it as well. Also, up-vote any answer you felt was helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Replace() method doesn't actually change the contents of a String. So you have to assign the new value to something.

An example:

```
someString = "First Example"

someString.Replace("First", "Second")

// someString is still "First Example"

newString = "Hello World".Replace("Hello", "Hi")

// newString is now "Hi World"
```

Some examples: http://www.dotnetperls.com/replace-vbnet

**Update:**

From your recent comment, it seems what you want it this:

```
TextBox1.Text.Replace("Hi", "temp").Replace("Hello", "HI").Replace("temp", "Hello")
```

Because the second replace is working on the result of the first replace. It's not working on the original text any more. So to switch 'hi' with 'hello' and 'hello' with 'hi' you have to have some intermediate value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I wanted that whatever the user types in 1st textbox, It should replace it and show the result in the Second textbox Like `rep.Text = ori.Text.Replace("Hello", "Hi").Replace("Hi", "Hello")`

Comment: @shahbaz Well if you are assigning the value of the replace() calls to another text box that's fine, but please edit your question to show that is what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Replace("Hi", "Hello").Replace("Hello", "HI")
End Sub
```

I guess this what you want, works for me

Comment: It doesn't as it replaces Hi in the first case to Hello, But doesn't replace Hello to Hi in the second case...

Comment: do you want "Hi max" >> "Hello max" >> "HI max"? so it's happening there

Comment: No no, I want this Hello Hi >> Hi Hello

Comment: You are not descriptive enough. anyway i get the feeling that you want to toggle something. maybe its not a replace :)

Comment: @shahbaz seems you are not replacing word but swapping. After the first replace, your word will be "Hello Hello", then the second replace will give you "HI HI"....I don't think that is what you want, you may need to think another way, e.g. a function for swapping your word